# Elasticsearch query based on timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

This is my elasticsearch query that intends to filter data between 11 pm and 12 pm on the day 2015.08.04. But it doesn't filter and gives many errors.

```
"query" : {"range" :
            {"@timestamp" :
              {"gt" : "2015-08-04  11:00:00", "lt" : "2015-08-04 12:00:00"} 
            } 
          }
```

Comment: What error did you see?, and can you reformat your query, it's really hard to read.

Comment: The error was the timestamp format parsing error.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It works with  the following query

```
{
   "query":{
      "range":{
         "@timestamp":{
            "gte":"2015-08-04T11:00:00",
            "lt":"2015-08-04T12:00:00"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that, @NasserTahani ? The `@` is part of the `@timestamp` variables name, and the query works correctly with it.