# ES delete_by_query how to set a time range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following POST request to delete some docs from an ES cluster

```
POST /aws-elb-*/_delete_by_query?requests_per_second=50&wait_for_completion=false
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "user_agent": [ "node", "axios" ],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

How do I add a timestamp so that only delete documents all but up to end of October 2020 for example?

Comment: Did you try something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619909/elasticsearch-query-based-on-timestamp) in a bool query ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply ned to add a `range` query on your date field. Like this:

```
POST /aws-elb-*/_delete_by_query?requests_per_second=50&wait_for_completion=false
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "lt": "2020-11-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "user_agent": [
              "node",
              "axios"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```